# Rename Function?

Tags: c, visual-studio, file, rename

I've tried using this code to move a file to another place.

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main ()
    {
      int result;
      char oldname[] ="C:\\Users\Mohammed Mehdi\Documents\Test.txt";
      char newname[] ="C:\\Users\Mohammed Mehdi\Documents\Test";
      result= rename(oldname, newname);
      if ( result == 0 )
        puts ( "File successfully renamed" );
      else
        perror( "Error renaming file" );
      return 0;
    }
```

The problem is that when I actually check all my computer files, nothing's happened. I've checked the return codes and it's returning 0 so it should be fine. I also have no errors.

I've looked at this question, but my code has no errors while I'm running it.
Rename function doesn't work, Visual Studio 2013 RC

Comment: Is there any return value from the rename call ?

Comment: No it just has a return 0 from the program

Comment: I think rename does not work the way you expect it to. Give MoveFileEx a try

Comment: Ok thanks I'll give it a go

Comment: @MohammedMehdi: Please *don't*! `rename` is standard, simple, and it works the way you expect it to! `MoveFileEx` will tie you directly into the badly designed Windows API! Just provide us more details, as we're lacking enough information to answer your question.

Comment: If the function used is [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/rename/) function, the implementation seems to be correct.

Comment: @Codor: Well, let's just expect M$ didn't introduced *yet* another function that does what it is supposed *not* to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each backslash should be escaped by another one:

```
char oldname[] ="C:\\Users\\Mohammed Mehdi\\Documents\\Test.txt";
char newname[] ="C:\\Users\\Mohammed Mehdi\\Documents\\Test";
```

Try adding

```
puts(oldname);
puts(newname);
```

before and after doing that change to see how the paths actually are.

You should also get warnings from Visual Studio:

```
warning C4129: 'M' : unrecognized character escape sequence
```

Comment: Thanks, got to remember that or next time.